# Организация потоков в Java

Tags: многопоточность, javafx

Работаю в JavaFX. Есть некоторые объекты в методе `start` и есть вложенный класс Run2( `class Run2 extends Thread` ). В нем есть метод `run` отвечающий за работу побочного потока. Как передать объект из метода `start` в метод `run`?

Comment: Код в студию, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял то:
1)

```
public class Main extends Aplication {

     private Object obj;

     @Override
     public void start( Stage stage ) {
         //some code
         obj = new SomeThing();
         Run2 run2 = new Run( obj );
         run2.start();
     }

     private class Run2 extends Thread {

         private final Objetc obj;

         public Run2( Object obj ) {
             this.obj = obj;
         }

         public void run() {
             //some code
         }
     }

}
```

2)

```
public class Main extends Aplication {

     private Object obj;

     @Override
     public void start( Stage stage ) {
         //some code
         obj = new SomeThing();
         Run2 run2 = new Run();
         run2.setObjetc( obj );
         run2.start();
     }

     private class Run2 extends Thread {

         private Objetc obj;

         pubic void setObject( Object obj ) {
             this.obj = obj;
         }

         public void run() {
             if ( obj == null )
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Объект не инициализирован!" );
             //some code
         }
     }

}
```

Не зная контекста сложно судить, но я бы порекомендовал в нагрузку [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) и [javafx.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-frame.html).